# Deploy iOS app directly from Xcode to iPad

Tags: ios, applications, xcode, developer-program

Since Xcode 7 was released, a target device has now free provisioning. A developer doesn't have to sign up for Apple Developer Program in order to test his/her app on an iOS device.

When you uploaded your application on an iPad or iPhone, you'll also have to trust the developer. So, on a device go to `Settings` >> `General` >> `Profile` >> `Developer Account Name` >> `Trust`.

The problem is an app with free provisioning works on your device only 7 days.

Is there a way to make it work perpetually on iPad (without building an app in Xcode again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make the app work "perpetually" without recompiling and rebuilding it in Xcode. This can be done by re-signing the finished binary using command line tools (i.e. essentially just replacing the developer signature instead of remaking the whole binary over and over). However, this is probably not what you want as you will need to transfer that new binary to the iPad every week.

If you want to make it work "perpetually" without having to reinstall the app, you will need to get it signed by someone with a real developer certificate (i.e. obtained from either the Apple Developer Program or the Enterprise Developer Program).